# luarocks 'gcc-plugin.h' build error

Tags: c++, gcc, luarocks

I am trying to use torch together with the hdf5 package. I am trying to install it via `luarocks install hdf5` but during the build phase I get an error regarding the gcc-plugin header. (gcc relies on clang backend). The complete error message is:

```
luarocks install --local hdf5
Installing https://luarocks.org/hdf5-2.0.0-1.src.rock...
Using https://luarocks.org/hdf5-2.0.0-1.src.rock... switching to 'build' mode
Warning: variable CFLAGS was not passed in build_variables
gcclua-config.h:1:10: fatal error: 'gcc-plugin.h' file not found
#include "gcc-plugin.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
env MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8 gcc -c -o gcclua.o -Iplugin/include -fPIC  -O2 -Wall -Wformat-security -I/usr/local/Cellar/lua/5.2.4_3/include gcclua.c
gcclua.c:7:10: fatal error: 'gcc-plugin.h' file not found
#include "gcc-plugin.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [gcclua.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [gcc] Error 2
make: *** [gcc-lua] Error 2
```

Just to give more information, I am relying on

```
gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
xcrun: error: couldn't stat toolchain: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/OSX10.11.xctoolchain' (errno=No such file or directory)
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Does anybody has maybe a hint how to fix this issue?

Every help is greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 6):

In addition to `gcc`, you need the headers, which on Linux you can get with `sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8-plugin-dev`. If you're on a different OS or version of gcc, just substitute the appropriate package manager / gcc version number.

Answer (score 1):

`gcc-plugin.h` is a part of GCC, so I think you'll really need to install `gcc` to get that. Clang provides a `gcc`-compatible front-end script but that merely presents a command-line driver with compatible flags.

You should be able to install GCC using Homebrew: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/86588

Answer (score 1):

I bet you tried to work on a CS287-16 class :). I have contacted the developer of this library who wasn't that easy to do something to solve the problem. Apparently he has no friends who have a Mac PC... As a workaround I could suggest you to use a Docker container with Linux in it to run Lua scripts. That's what I have ended up with...

Here's the Docker image I was talking about: https://github.com/aoboturov/cs287-16-lua. You could build it yourself and the just run as a Docker container :)